# Javascript Three Dimensional Array , get error

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to create a three dimensional array in JavaScript but I'm getting an error in Chrome:

```
Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
```

My JavaScript looks like this:

```
 function ThreeDimensionalArray(iRows,iCols,iHig)
   {
      var i;
      var j;
      var z;
      var a = new Array(iRows);
      for (i=0; i < iRows; i++)
         d  {
           a[i] = new Array(iCols);
           for (j=0; j < iCols; j++)
               {           
                  var a[i][j] = new Array(iHig);
                  for (z=0; z < iHig; z++){
                  a[i][j][z] = "";
               };
          };
     };
  return(a);
  }; 

  var hello = ThreeDimensionalArray(3,3,3);
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/JknVF/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

`var a[i][j] = new Array(iHig);`

to

`a[i][j] = new Array(iHig);`.

`var` indicates you want to define a new variable. `a` is already defined.

Comment: Also this: `d  {` and unclosed bracket for `for (z=0...`

Comment: @Max I think the `d {` was a typo since it wasn't in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Remove "var" from the following line:

```
var a[i][j] = new Array(iHig);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've corrected your code to make a working version here:

http://jsfiddle.net/JknVF/7/